# Is there a way in Xcode/Objective C to assign variable/object names which are calucated at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, variables, data-structures, software-design

I want to created a few variables/objects at runtime in my code. But I don't know how many I need. Is there a way in objective C to assign a name to an object, where the name is calculated before the initialisation?

Example:

The basic structue of the each name should be: variable + Number + a Letter e.g. variable2b

```
NSNumber (calculated name) = [NSNumber numberwithInt:@1];
NSNumber variable2b = [NSNumber numberwithInt:@2];
NSNumber variable3c = [NSNumber numberwithInt:@3];
```

Comment: If you don't know how many you need, then you're looking at using an `NSMutableArray`. You don't need to mess around with dynamic names like this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant: Perhaps you should have chosen the name *The Pedantic Croissant*. ;-)

Comment: @Zaph Probably that's more descriptive, but not nearly as cool :P (BTW, in my opinion, programmers should really all be quite pedantic. Programs have to be perfect, mathematics is precise and errors are fatal...)

Comment: "Programs have to be perfect" Unfortunately I have gotten a lot ]of pushback on that topic WRT consumer apps such as iOS.

Comment: @Zaph that only means that project managers have insufficient knowledge about programming...

Comment: Yes and no. I have gotten that from most of the developers I talk to, possibly for the same reason: insufficient knowledge about programming. I have been told by most that a single method of 5,000 lines is fine or better than a number of smaller methods. From a manager I know I got that there is just not enough time to write the code correctly because of tine-to-market constraints. I was told that there was not even one hour/month to devote to learning how to program better. It is all very discouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, variables do not have "names" at runtime.  These are simply useful to help you, as the person creating the code, to differentiate between variables before compiling.  Under most circumstances (and certainly at your level of experience), variable "names" are useless at runtime.

If you have a number of related variables you need, you want a [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure).  This is a means of storing variables and constants which are accessed in various ways depending on the type of data structure.  An array (or, as mentioned elsewhere, an `NSMutableArray` for an undetermined number of items) is accessed through an index.  Something along the lines of `array[0]` or `array[index]`.  A dictionary (like NSDictionary) is accessed through a "key", such as `dictionary[@"mouse"]` or `dictionary[keys[index]]`

There are more about which you could learn through the linked Wiki article, or just Googling 'data structures objective c' or something similar.